# How to extract pattern from string using Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
abcd  /  email@email.com ABC-1234567  /  44kkkkkk
```

Could you help me extract the part with `ABC-1234567` where `1234567` can be any number.

Comment: Did you try: `\bABC-[0-9]+\b`

Comment: If the amount of digits is always the same you can add {7} instead of the + after [0-9] in the regex from @anubhava to state that a number has to occur 7 times there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
\S+-\d+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mL4sH7/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex

```
ABC-\d+
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/3NZAqOlj9y)